# is accessing two vectors in maps impossible?

Tags: c++

Since I am beginner to c++, I was trying to play with . So, I succeeded in

```
map<string,int>
```

And,

```
map <string, vector<int> >
```

But, I was curious if having two vectors in a map can be accessible. So, what should I do?

```
int main()
{
    map<vector<string>,vector<int> > a;
    vector<int> okay;
    vector<string> knot;
    knot.push_back("name1");  //this for inserting in vector<string>
    knot.push_back("name2");
    okay.push_back(1);   //this on for vector<int>
    okay.push_back(2);
    a[knot]=okay;

    map<vector<string>,vector<int> >::iterator i=a.begin();
    cout<<i->first<<endl;  //error shows here, how am i accessing this?
    ++i;
    cout<<i->first;  //this too. Function resembles the same of above. So, ERROR!! 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i->first` is a `vector<string>` and `cout` cannot print vectors.

Comment: so, that would mean I need to access each values in container by iterator? If so, how would i be able to do so?

Comment: you have to overload operator << for vector<string> to get it work

Comment: TIL that vectors have lexicographic compare

Comment: @michaeltang: You're not allowed to do that. You can only overload operators if at least one of the arguments is your type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
cout<<i->first<<endl;
```

You are doing the right thing, but `i->first` returns a `vector` because you have a `map` of `vectors`. There is no overloaded `<<` (print) operator for `vector<string>` (but you could make your own). But if you:

```
auto temp = i->first;
for(const auto &a : temp) {
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

This will print all the elements stored in the vector in `i->first`.

If you wish the print the first element stored in the vector, you can do:

```
cout << *((i->first).begin()) << endl; //iterator method or
cout << (i->first)[0] << endl;
```

Do not attempt to print vector elements without checking emptiness.

Comment: ... the former being preferred if there is a chance the vector is *empty* (and one of them may well-be).

Comment: How about wrapping the range based for loop solution in an overloaded `template<typename T> ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const vector<T> & vec)`